# How to exclude child from layouting

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

Look at example:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Yellow">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"/>

    <Button Grid.Column="1">
        <Viewbox>
            <Path Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Black" Data="M 0,0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Here is a button with vector graphics and I want it to be as small as it needs to be (restrict vector graphics from *exploding*).

Here is how it looks like and how I want it to be:

[image][image]

---

There are several possible solutions how to **overcome** the problem, to list few:

1. By binding `Width`/`Height` to some other element (this has issues with designer):

   ```
   ...
   <Button Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=textBlock}" ...>
   ...
   ```

   This is often used together with the *ghost*: special invisible element used by others (have no relationship with it) to layout themselves.
2. By hosting element inside `Canvas` (which is *magical* container), but then `Canvas` itself require layouting.

   You can try putting `Button` inside `Canvas`. This will cause parent `Grid` only take height of `TextBlock`, but then there is another problem: how to position (layout) `Canvas` itself, so that its children are layout properly, kek.

---

In example above I don't actually want `TextBlock` to be a *sister* of `Button`, they could overlap (you wouldn't want the button to be hidden if available size is not enough, it should rather overlap something less important), I just want them to have same parent (if it moves - children will move). Confused? Look here:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock ... />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" ... />
</Grid>
```

This layout has same problems and can be solved similarly.

---

Now try to abstract from concrete examples above.

What I **actually** want: is to learn how to *exclude* element from layout of container. Like if element is collapsed, so the parent container will measure children sizes (except this element), layout children and then, after layouting is finished, element suddenly become visible and is restricted by parent container, while can use various alignments.

Does it make sense what I am asking? Maybe custom container is the way? Or do I miss something existing and obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to constrain the `Path` by the size of the described geometry, it's as simple as setting `StretchDirection="DownOnly"` on the `Viewbox`.

If you *truly* want it to request no vertical space of its own, and have its height determined by its layout 'neighbors' (in this case, the `TextBlock`), then you'll need to wrap it in a custom layout container.  But you can't simply *exclude* it from layout--at least not completely.  If you did, the element would always end up with zero width and height.  Instead, you can measure in *two passes*, with the first pass requesting a child height of zero, and the second pass basing the requested size on the arrange size given after the first pass.

I *think* the container below will give you what you want, but **be warned** that I haven't tested it thoroughly.  Use at your own risk.

```cs
public class ZeroHeightDecorator : Border
{
    private Size _lastSize;
    private Size _idealSize;

    protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject added, DependencyObject removed)
    {
        base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(added, removed);
        _idealSize = new Size();
        _lastSize = new Size();
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var child = this.Child;
        if (child == null)
            return new Size();
        if (child.IsMeasureValid)
            child.Measure(new Size(Math.Max(_lastSize.Width, constraint.Width), _lastSize.Height));
        else
            child.Measure(new Size(constraint.Width, 0d));
        _idealSize = child.DesiredSize;
        return new Size(_idealSize.Width, 0d);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        var child = this.Child;
        if (child != null)
        {
            if (arrangeSize != _lastSize)
            {
                // Our parent will assume our measure is the same if the last
                // arrange bounds are still available, so force a reevaluation.
                this.InvalidateMeasure();
            }
            child.Arrange(new Rect(arrangeSize));
        }
        _lastSize = arrangeSize;
        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

A more flexible container would allow you to specify *which* dimension(s) to minimize: `Width` , `Height`, or `Neither`, or `Both`.  Feel free to extend it :).

Example in action:

```xml
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Yellow">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" />

  <t:ZeroHeightDecorator Grid.Column="1">
    <Button>
      <Viewbox>
        <Path Fill="Black" Data="M 0,0 H 100 V 100 H 0 Z" />
      </Viewbox>
    </Button>
  </t:ZeroHeightDecorator>
</Grid>
```

[image: Screenshot]